# Close bootstrap modal without using "hide" and "data-dismiss"

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to close bootstrap modal box conditionally. If I use 
`$('#modal').modal('hide');` this, some thing goes wrong with my code. And If I use `data-dismiss="modal"` in the HTML template, modal dismiss action performs before my actual functionality should be perform on button click.

So, there is any other way to close bootstrap modal or any idea to use `data-dismiss="modal"` at run time?

Comment: Elaborate it clearly that how you want to hide under what circumstances?

Comment: This library might help http://bootboxjs.com/index.html#about

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it with auto modal closing behavior which uses the `data-dismiss` attribute itself or with the manual modal opening (as i guess you are doing currently) , by subscribing to `hide` event and use `preventDefault` on the event.

```
$('yourmodalselector').on('hide',function(e){
   if(yourConditionNotToCloseMet){
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D827F/)

#### [Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/exx5e/)

See [Documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

hide event event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been called, which gets called wither way and this is the best place to prevent the modal from closing.

Comment: may i know from where the coding of `data-dismiss` comes from ?

Comment: @PardeepJain Sorry i did not understand your question.

Comment: i mean i know `data-dismiss` used to dismiss the modal. but where the code has written for the same. i.e `data-dismiss` is code of bootstrap.js or .css or anyone else ?

Comment: It should be in the bootstrap implementation and you would use it on the template.

Comment: in bootstrap.js or in bootstrap.css ?

Answer (score 3):

Make another button like this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg shiny" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
```

This button contains `data-dismiss="modal"` .You can hide this if you want.

Now You can use any other function in a customized way and when you want to hide the modal you can call

```
$(".btn-warning").click();
```