# How to send form data to remote URL and the result display in Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, bootstrap-modal

I have a CakePHP form and I want to allow users to display a preview. So there is a preview submit button `#btn_submit_preview` and when user clicks the button, data from the form are serialized and sent to my controller. This controller saves the data and return HTML view output with preview:

```
 $('#btn_submit_preview').click(function (event) {
    var formData = $("#OfferAddForm").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/offers/preview/",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```

After data are passed back to the page I need to display them in a Boostrap modal window. I have these HTML source code for modal.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content" id="content">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question:** is the way how I open the "preview" correct or should I do something else? I am quite sure about assigning returned data back to modal window - `$('#content').html(data);` maybe I should return all HTML source for modal window with preview data and open it only...?

Comment: This is not the correct way of opening a modal.

Comment: Well, What is the correct way of opening a modal? Thanks.

Comment: Create a button which has data-toggle and hide it.after that In your function  use $('#some_id').click();.Remember first fill all the values and then open your modal.Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972809/close-bootstrap-modal-without-using-hide-and-data-dismiss/27055175#27055175)

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. Is there any support in official documentation for this?

Comment: Nopes.This is my own invention.

Comment: I think that opening modal via JavaScript is ok, as you can see here - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: Thank for the info. buddy.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have now is perfectly fine. I wouldn't return the HTML source for the entire modal, I'd just grab the HTML for the email and display it on my modal, this helps to achieve a better separation of concerns IMO.