# Bootstrap Modal Close

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a 2 modals in the root of my markup and although the docs say not to use more than one at a time I have a scenario where from a users perspective I think it would make the most sense to have 2 modals.  Problem is that once the second modal opens, it will dismiss the first as well as the second.  Is there any way to target a specific modal or id with `data-dismiss="modal"` as I am assuming this is where the logic for dismissing modals is?

Comment: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3233

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16972809/close-bootstrap-modal-without-using-hide-and-data-dismiss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

Is the correct syntax to close/hide the modal with id myModal (you can test this on the Bootstrap documentation page).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use JQuery//Bootstrap to close them like:

```
$('#modal1').modal('hide');
```

EDIT:CMedina was faster ;)